# Excision in the stable homotopy category

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

Is there a way to make precise the statements (if it holds at all) that excision holds in the stable homotopy category? I am a beginner in this kind of things, and the stable homotopy category for me is just CW spectra with maps up to homotopy, following Adams.

I mean, suppose you have an inclusion of subspaces $B \subset A$ of a topological space $X$ with $\overline B \subset A°$. Is it true that $(X-B, A-B)$ is stably homotopically equivalent to $(X, A)$? You may make assumptions on these spaces, if needed.

I have the vague feeling that this is true since $\Omega$-spectra correspond to cohomology theories, for which exchision hold, but I can not make this statement precise or prove it.

Comment: Probably some form of what you're looking for can be shown using the Blakers-Massey theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The only reasonable notion of stable homotopy equivalence of pairs $(A,B) \rightarrow (C,D)$ that is compatible with your question is an equivalence $\Sigma^\infty (A \cup \operatorname{cone} (B)) \rightarrow \Sigma^\infty (C \cup \operatorname{cone}(D))$.

Now given a map of pairs $(A,B) \rightarrow (C,D)$ that induces an isomorphism on relative homology, it is easy to show (provided you know basic stable homotopy theory) that the induced map $\Sigma^\infty (A \cup \operatorname{cone} (B)) \rightarrow \Sigma^\infty (C \cup \operatorname{cone}(D))$ is a stable equivalence. This is because relative homology coincides with homology of the mapping cone of the inclusion (this is a consequence of excision), and a map of finite spectra is an equivalence, if and only if, it is a homology equivalence (this is Whitehead's theorem in spectra).

Hence, the homological statement of excision implies the stable homotopy version of excision, i.e.  $\Sigma^\infty (X - B \cup \operatorname{cone} (A-B)) \rightarrow \Sigma^\infty (X \cup \operatorname{cone}(A))$ is an equivalence.

Comment: Are you assuming these are CW spectra with inclusions of sub-CW spectra?

Comment: @arnett Nothing needs to be a CW spectrum here. But this is basically a feature of spectra. The equivalences are detected just by homotopy groups.

Comment: @arnett Stable equivalences like this come up when studying Spanier-Whitehead duality. If you read some of the earlier papers on it, you will see the study the suspension spectra of these coned off pairs.

Comment: I've though about it a little bit, but I think I don't know enough stable homotopy yet. Could you please add some more details on how to show that $\Sigma^\infty \mathrm{cone}(B \hookrightarrow A) \to \Sigma^\infty \mathrm{cone}(D \hookrightarrow C)$ is a stable equivalence and on how finiteness plays a role?

Comment: @arnett It is a homology equivalence of finite spectra; any homology equivalence of finite spectra (after some amount of suspensions) can be realized as a map of simply connected spaces that is a homology equivalence. A homology equivalence of simply connected spaces is a homotopy equivalence and it remains so after applying suspension spectra.